# College/University list for populating an Auto-complete field?

Tags: api, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an auto-complete text field with a list of known Universities and Colleges. Do you know where I can get this sort of list? Or is there a public API that contains this data?

Comment: I can see why some recommendations should be marked off topic. However, I really like this type of question. I honestly wasn't sure where else to look for suggestions/discussions on where to get info for this. IMO this is a great fit for stackoverflow. But I can definitely see there is a fine line where questions like this can get out of hand. Just my 2cents.

Comment: api.collegeai.com has an autocomplete API https://api.collegeai.com/json-api/guide--get-college-information

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found that [IPEDS (Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System)](http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/) is probably the most authoritative source for this data (and tons more related to it), and it's easy to export.

That page has a bunch of different tools for exporting different sets of the data in various common ways, but they all wrap around the "Download Custom Data Files" tool which is the most basic.

For a list (rather than data on a single institution), you would go to that custom data file page, and click on "By Group" to select the actual filters to use to limit what list of institutions you want (and what year of datasets). Then you click "Search", and it will provide a sample list of your results. From there, you click "Continue" to select which variables you want in the report with each of the institutions you've already filtered down to.

There's **tons** of variables, but in this case, you'll find everything you need under "Institutional Characteristics" most likely. Once you've selected all of the columns of information you want, click the big "Continue" button up top. You will then be presented with a bunch of download links for your data in a few various formats including CSV.

Comment: I took a quick browse and it looks quite thorough. Exactly what I was looking for. You mentioned it's easy to export the data. I couldn't figure it out. Could you walk me through how you pulled a list of "institutions"?

Comment: Instructions have been added.

Answer (score 6):

For quick results, try http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/GetDownloadFile.aspx - it has complete data sets ready to download with all the key information.

Comment: I made an API that wraps those results: https://github.com/karllhughes/colleges

Works for my small-time purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The US Federal Aid Application site (http://www.fafsa.ed.gov/) has a very complete list, although I'm not sure how many non-US universities are listed (some are).

You could consider starting an application and scraping the list.

Comment: Where can I find that list on that website?

Answer (score 1):

After a few moments of review, I'm pretty sure that fafsa doesn't want that list used by the public or make it easily accessible to the public.

If you go to their school search form (https://fafsa.ed.gov/FAFSA/app/schoolSearch?locale=en_EN) it uses autocomplete to provide the filtered data. I didn't feel like looking for too long at the script to see if I could figure out a URI that might give the entire listing, but I'm pretty sure they don't want people using their bandwidth. I will continue looking elsewhere. I'll try to post back if I find something more like what we're looking for.

...I'm back. I found dbpedia.org as a possible source (for this & MUCH more). I also tweaked an example to list all it's universities in alphabetical order and saved the html output for my own use.

I also found
http://infochimps.com/search?query=universities
this site apparently only "deals" with datasets (some free, some not)

I'm still hoping to find a "straight up" web resource that I can ping with queries for JSON.

ahhhh what'ya gonna do!?!? 8)

Answer (score 1):

You might try the Department of Education: http://www.ed.gov/developer Data is available by API call or as csv. About to build the same experience using the API endpoint so I'll update with notes.