# PHP/MySQL List of university coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates

I am trying to get the user's coordinates and get a short list of the nearest universities in the area.

So my initial thoughts were to populate my own MySQL with a heck of a lot of universities and coordinates, so I can use a searching algorithm to match the closest handful of universities  with the data in my database.

Is that realistic to accomplish?  To find a list of all universities, I have looked at: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970789/college-university-list-for-populating-an-auto-complete-field), and when I went to [the site](http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/InstitutionList.aspx), it seemed like the files were exported as .uid?  I'm not sure how to deal with this.  Also, if I have a list of universities, how can I get the coordinates of them?  Would geocoder work?  If it's possible I would also like a list of high schools, but ignore that for now.

What do you think?  Am I missing something?  Is there a more efficient way to get a list of the closest universities to a user?

Comment: I wanted to check the site ed.gov for you but I am receiving `Security Violation Detected` so I can't help you now. Sorry. Good question though! I don't see that often, a user with 13 rep and a good question with good effort :)

Comment: a broken aspx educational site, theres a surprise :x  it finally loaded for me after a few tries. Here is a direct link to a csv with 7000+ universities and their addresses http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2011.zip skimming through the list it looks like it also includes Beauty schools so you may need to filter out extra unwanted institution types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the list of all universities with its address, you can use The Google Geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ to retrieve the coordinates. You can write a script that fill a table of a database with the information.

Edit:

I've found this site: http://www.a2zcolleges.com/address_phone/addressindex.htm, perhaps it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)? Perhaps you could do a search for universities, then parse the results.

Looks like you could do a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), then use a [Place Type](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) of *university*.

Answer (score 0):

could you get away with just the latitude/longitude of the city a university is in, or is this for a local search where +/- a mile or 2 matters? Maxmind offers a free database of city coordintates you could cross reference against a list of universities by city

[Maxmind world cities](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities)

**Edit**

Here is a list of US zipcode long/lat coordinates you can use to cross reference with the university address csv database link I posted in the comment above. If you need international mailing codes, they have several good links on the maxmind postal codes section

[US Zip Codes](http://pablotron.org/files/zipcodes-csv-10-Aug-2004.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Geocoding API has usage limits, I believe. I have retrieved geo coordinates for colleges in bulk in two ways. The first is complicated and only mentioned for posterity.

(1) This way uses a very circuitous process that involves OpenRefine (http://openrefine.org/) -- formerly Google Refine. It needs Java on your computer (Windows, Mac, Linux) to run. But because this is complex, all I'm going to say is that you need to:

- (a) add the dbpedia.org reconciliation service in OpenRefine;
- (b) run a reconciliation on your colleges list using the schema
  dbo:university;
- (c) retrieve the dbpedia url from the reconciled column;
- (d) convert the url to the .json version;
- (e) run a "fetch urls" using the .json URLs;
- (f) Parse the results for the coordinates using the GREL functions
  built-in (or Jython).

You can see how circuitous it is, but it suits me because I use OpenRefine daily.

(2) The less circuitous route is to run a SPARQL query directly on dbpedia.org using your colleges list. However, SPARQL is an acquired taste, with potentially confusing syntax. I had to do a lot of reading and hit-and-miss testing before getting it right.

Now, just to tie this altogether, dbpedia.org is the structured equivalent of wikipedia.org. You might sneer at that, but when it comes to college / university entries, some of the basic information is usually very accurate -- and that includes geo coordinates, established date, location, website, etc.

Comment: Actually, after I wrote all the above out, I recalled an answer someone gave for another question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970789/college-university-list-for-populating-an-auto-complete-field]. There's a reference to nearbycolleges.info REST API (but it is not public).

Comment: Aternatively, If you don't mind data from 2013, data.gov has a directory listing of 7,769 institutions of higher learning. (Colleges and universities run just over 2000 schools. The rest include non-degree granting schools/ professional schools. For example, including beauty schools.) Here is the data.gov URL:

https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/032e19b4-5a90-41dc-83ff-6e4cd234f565/resource/38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4