# College/University data API

Tags: json, api, web-scraping

I'm trying to build an application that allows users to look up a specific university and see data about it (admission rate, SAT scores, size, etc.). However, I can't find an API/database that I can use as it doesn't seem like they have a REST API that's accessible via a GET URL request.I saw so many apps having all this information, but I can't find any relevant API.
Does anyone know a way I could access this information? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [College/University list for populating an Auto-complete field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970789/college-university-list-for-populating-an-auto-complete-field)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just figured it out. Turns out you can use the IPEDS database to get this info, but it doesn't offer an API to do it. Go to [IPEDS](http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/InstitutionByName.aspx) and create a group of institutions you want (ex. all 4-year, degree granting universities in the United States), select what variables you want (address, admission rate, etc.), then finally export the data in CSV. If you want the data in a less terrible format, just convert it to JSON or whatever you'd like.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.mashape.com/zaidos/gradnote#!endpoint-Institutions ?

Comment: IPEDS database is the best bet. They have SAT score but not GRE or GMAt score

Answer (score 5):

An extensive collection of data in json, csv, pdf, and other formats is at:

http://www.ed.gov/developer

One funny thing: if you take one of their download links:

https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/032e19b4-5a90-41dc-83ff-6e4cd234f565/resource/38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4/download/userssharedsdfpostscndryunivsrvy2010dirinfo.csv

and you change the .csv to .json, you still get a csv file.