# Is There a Web Service for Retrieving All University Names Worldwide

Tags: web-services

I'd like to use a web service or a different solution to retrieve the names of all higher education institutions (universities, colleges, technical schools etc.) wordwide. This will enable the users of a job application web app to enter/select the higher education institution they attended in a consistent manner.

Could you please point out to such a resource?

Comment: You could query [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/).

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't used google or stackoverflow to search for it too much... There are similar (easy findable) questions here in SO.

Comment: @sergioFC thanks for the dbpedia info. What I'm looking for is a readily available resource, such as a web service, that can be used to retrieve the complete list of wordwide higher education institutions without much extra processing. Wikipedia list is a good source. To be able to use their data, I would need to write a custom program to parse (extract) the useful info, and to store it in a DB for example.

Comment: Maybe one of this API related questions is useful for you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970789/college-university-list-for-populating-an-auto-complete-field) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775893/college-university-data-api)

Comment: List of 9000 universities (https://github.com/endSly/world-universities-csv/blob/master/world-universities.csv), included country and web. In CSV format => easy to extract info.

Comment: Please set your comment with the "List of 9000 universities" as an answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with that info.

Comment: I upvoted this question. Whoever closed this question is just rude. This question is 100% valid and useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **dbpedia**.

Example query to get 50 universities:

```
SELECT ?university
WHERE {
    ?university rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/University> 
} LIMIT 50
```

You could use it at [dbpedia sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). You could also search for generic educational institution, college, etc.
Or you could simply use [wikipedia universities list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_universities_and_colleges_by_country)

**EDIT:**
[List of 9000 universities](https://github.com/endSly/world-universities-csv/blob/master/world-universities.csv), included country and web. Data is easy to extract as dataset its in CSV format. Link to [github project](https://github.com/endSly/world-universities-csv/)